# How to access Cognito functions and Elasticache from the same AWS lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to write AWS lambda function which gets user from AWS Cognito using `AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminGetUser` and then stores some data into AWS Elasticache (Redis). The parts work fine separately, but not together, as it seems that when I enable VPC for Lambda (to be able to access Elasticache), I loose access to Cognito (Lambda times out).

Is there a way to access both services from single lambda function, or my approach is totally wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can for sure. You need to create a NAT Gateway or NAT instance in a public subnet of your VPC, then add a rule to the route table that enables NAT from lambda's security group. I don't think there are public Cognito IP addresses, therefore your security outbound group rule CIDR would be 0.0.0.0/0.

More details are available on official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html) and also there are tons of tutorials online, because it's a common problem. Good luck!

P.S. Don't forget to add permissions for `adminGetUser` action to lambda's IAM role.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid this extra complexity and cost associated with NAT Gateway. Also for me it was somehow counter-intuitive to access Cognito (which looks like internal service to lambda) via NAT Gateway (which usually are used to access services on public Internet).

Comment: Yeah, they provide VPC endpoints for such cases. Currently you can set up endpoints for S3 and DynamoDB only, as far as I remember. They solve the same problem NAT solves, except that the traffic doesn't actually leave AWS network. And they are cheaper than NAT Gateway. Unfortunately, there's no endpoint for cognito at this moment of time.

Comment: So to add to the confusion, in my example I have bunch of Lambdas managed by CloudFormation, and all of them interact with Cognito, but only one does Cognito+Redis. So for the rest of functions I do not need any VPC (i.e. I can access Cognito directly from Lambda), but for this one separate case I have to have VPC+NAT gateway to be able to access Cognito and Redis. Thanks for your explanation, that is perhaps the way to go for me now.